How to process refund to a bank account for payment made via credit card or cash at the store using Stripe?
I am exploring Stripe payment gateway for an online and physical store and have some questions that I could not get clarity about via Stripe documentation.
Mode of payments on the online store: Stripe payment link (Enabled for credit card payments).
Mode of payments at the physical store: Cash and Stripe payment link (Enabled for credit card payments).
If a refund needs to be processed for a payment done via Stripe link i.e. credit card, then it can be done via the refund API.
However, if the payment was done in cash at the physical store, is there a way to provide refund using Stripe services by adding bank details? Perhaps, by sending a link to customer where they can add bank details and refunds can be processed?

In general that type of feature is called "unlinked refunds", which Stripe doesn't publicly support but maybe you could ask them directly what options exist. In general this(issuing refund without explicitly being connected to an existing pay-in) is not an easy problem to solve though since it's basically sending money to an arbitrary bank account and is thus open to fraud/sanction concerns, and so on.

Thanks @karllekko for the quick response. I did email Stripe support and they referred me to a page which explains refunds for payments made via bank transfers.
I agree to your point about fraud and sanctions. In some countries this would be called money laundering or converting black cash to white. What would you suggest as a best approach to processing refunds for payments made in cash?
